# Can I use a scanner connected via USB on a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: usb, windows-mobile, scanner

Can I use a device such as a scanner connected via USB port to a Windows Mobile based device?

I don't have any concrete devices in mind - just general question - is this setup supported?

What I'm trying to achieve is a low power, always running interface so people without a computer can quickly scan any document and have it processed according do some rules that I will design.

I'm aware of the fact that there are network enabled scanners/printers, but those cannot be used in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of caveats to this:

1. The scanner must be able to operate off USB power or be battery powered (assuming that you don't want to have to plug the scanner into the mains!).
2. If the scanner needs USB power the mobile device must be able provide that power over it's USB port.
3. The mobile device will need a scanner driver.

If all these conditions can be met then I don't see why you can't have what you want.